# Possible to store 3D features such as dome into geospatial database?

Tags: postgis, 3d, database

Is it possible to store 3D features such as dome into geospatial database such as PostGIS?

I know that it can store x,y,z data, can such complex features be stored into database?

Comment: Are you meaning the 3D equivalent of a true curve?

Comment: It is not necessary be a true curve, but the way of describing such shape.

Comment: You can store CityGML in PostGIS databases.

Comment: I have just had researched on it, how about TIN and POLYHEDRALSURFACE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS 2.0 and higher has several 3D geometry types:

> For 3-D and 4-D geometries, the extra dimensions are added as extra
>   coordinates for each vertex in the geometry, and the geometry type is
>   enhanced to indicate how to interpret the extra dimensions. Adding the
>   extra dimensions results in three extra possible geometry types for
>   each geometry primitive:
>
> - Point (a 2-D type)i is joined by PointZ, PointM and PointZM types.
> - Linestring (a 2-D type) is joined by LinestringZ, LinestringM and LinestringZM types.
> - Polygon (a 2-D type) is joined by PolygonZ, PolygonM and PolygonZM types.
>
> And so on.
>
> ...
>
> In addition to higher-dimensional forms of the standard types, PostGIS
>   includes a few new types that make sense in a 3-D space:
>
> - The TIN type allows you to model triangular meshes as rows in your database.
> - The POLYHEDRALSURFACE allows you to model volumetric objects in your database.

[Boundless](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/3d.html)

Comment: What is the difference of TIN and POLYHEDRALSURFACE in terms of their usage?

Comment: @HaroldChan: TIN is just the top surface of a terrain or similar surface. Polyhedron has all sides represented - more complex.